# Notice: Array to string conversion in line 74 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'51

Tags: php

I am getting this error when i am trying to pass my id in statusUpdate function. The UPDATE query showing me this error. Can anyone help me to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

```
 <select class="form-control" name="setstatus">                    
  <option value="0">Not Solved</option>
  <option value="1">Solved</option>
</select>

<?php
$id = $_GET['bugid'];
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
   $setstatus = $_POST['setstatus'];
   $insertreport = $pd->statusUpdate($_POST, $id ); 
 }
?>
public function statusUpdate($id){
    $setstatus = $_POST['setstatus'];
    $query     = "UPDATE `bugstable` SET `status`= $setstatus WHERE `bugid`= $id ";
    $updated_rows = $this->db->update($query);
     if ($updated_rows) {
      echo "<span class='success'>Successfully.</span>";
    }else {
     echo "<span class='error'>Not Updated !</span>";
     }
}
```

Comment: `$pd->statusUpdate($_POST, $id )` y are u using $_POST here? and your function only accepting 1 param `public function statusUpdate($id){`

Comment: solved...thanks for noticing me.

Comment: good to know that Hasan

Answer (score 0):

*Well, first of all you must need to pass status param in your function where you are calling:*

```
$setstatus = intval($_POST['setstatus']);
$insertreport = $pd->statusUpdate($setstatus,$id);
```

*Second, than you just need to add first param as status in your function where you define:*

```
public function statusUpdate($setstatus,$id){
    $query     = "UPDATE `bugstable` SET `status`= $setstatus WHERE `bugid`= $id ";
    /** Your rest code **/
```